# How can you view your skill level?

Tags: dota-2

After a recent Dota 2 patch it is no longer possible to search by player name. They have also removed the "skill level" function from their API, which means that you can't really see your skill level on websites like dotabuff.

Is it even possible to view your skill level? If so, **how?**